# Using GraphicBuffers to fast read from a texture

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, egl

I am working on some code that runs some GPGPU code on Android using shaders. Usually a `Framebuffer` is used so the result of the computation is stored in a texture. Also the input data is usually a texture. To improve performance it would be great to get rid of `glTexImage2D` and `glReadPixels` to upload and download images to and from the GPU memory space. All the code related to OpenGL is native.

On Android `GraphicBuffer` can be used on Android for this propose because in mobile devices gpu memory is just host RAM memory. This structure allows to use `memcpy` to transfer data with the GPU. This should be faster than using OpenGL functions.

I have been using this very cited articles [[1](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-opengl-es-to-accelerate-apps-with-legacy-2d-guis)][[2](https://vec.io/posts/faster-alternatives-to-glreadpixels-and-glteximage2d-in-opengl-es)][[3](http://snorp.net/2011/12/16/android-direct-texture.html)] to successfully upload textures to the Android's GPU memory space using `GraphicBuffer`.

Later I tried to use the same method to move the texture data back into CPU space but I'm still having some problems with it. According to answer [[7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25535693/4116251)] it should not be possible. But further reading of some other answers in StackOverflow seem to tell otherwise. Some cases of a successful replacement of `glReadPixels` by a `memcpy` from a `GraphicBuffer` are reported in [[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564203/what-is-wrong-when-i-use-eglimage-replace-glreadpixels-in-ndk-program)][[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24448977/unexpected-pixel-data-layout-when-reading-from-graphicbuffer)][[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151259/replacing-glreadpixels-with-egl-khr-image-base-for-faster-pixel-copy)]. Most seem to say that placing `glFinish` just before locking and reading the `GraphicBuffer` makes its content updated as expected by the time it is read.

In my experience it did not work out of the box but there really seem to be a timing problem. Just calling `glFinish` does not seem to be enough but if I wait a few milliseconds before reading the buffer (i.e. placing a `sleep`) then the content seem to be correct. This is really not a solution as it ends up being slower than the original `glReadPixels` solution (and anyway it wouldn't be a very reliable solution), but shows that the content IS actually updated at some point.

My questions would be:

- Is it really true that `GraphicBuffer` can not be read directly as said in [[7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25535693/4116251)], or has something changed since then?
- Is it just a coincidence that it seem to work for other people?
- Is there a better way to enforce the memory to be updated (e.g. a stronger `glFinish` call)?

Comment: Regarding the lag between `glFinish()` and the arrival of the pixels... Are you locking the GraphicBuffer *after* `glFinish()` returns? What device and version of Android are you using?

Comment: Hi fadden, yes I do lock the buffer just after `glFinish` and before reading from it. It is all done from the same thread. The device is a Samsung Galaxy Note II N7100 with Android 4.4.2. Thanks!

Comment: You can try using `glReadPixels()` to read a single pixel. Generally speaking, the driver must finish rendering before it can read the final pixels back, so when `glReadPixels()` returns you know the rendering has completed. If you just read one pixel the overhead should be minimal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527332/android-7-graphicbuffer-alternative-for-direct-access-to-opengl-texture-memory/54085479#54085479