# Android 7 GraphicBuffer alternative for direct access to OpenGL texture memory

Tags: android, performance, opengl-es, android-ndk, android-7.0-nougat

The only way to get profit from the fact, that mobile devices have shared memory for CPU and GPU was using `GrphicBuffer`. But since Android 7 restrict access to private native libs (including gralloc) it is impossible to use it any more. The question - is there any alternative way to get direct memory access to texture's pixel data?

I know, that something similar can be done using PBO (pixel buffer object). But it still does additional memory copy, which is undesirable. Especially if we know, that there was way to do it with zero copies.

There are many apps, which used this feature, because it can heavily increase the performance. I think many developers are in stuck with this problem now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Android 8 / API 26 (sorry not for Android 7...)

[Hardware Buffer APIs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html#hardware_buffer_apis) are alts for `GrphicBuffer()`.

> The native hardware buffer API  lets you
>   directly allocate buffers to create your own pipelines for
>   cross-process buffer management. You can allocate an AHardwareBuffer
>   and use it to obtain an EGLClientBuffer resource type via the
>   eglGetNativeClientBufferANDROID extension.

[NDK revision history](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history)

Minimum revision of NDK is 15c (July 2017)

> Android NDK, Revision 15c (July 2017)
>   Added native APIs for Android 8.0.
>   * Hardware Buffer API

`android/hardware_buffer_jni.h` is in the directory `(NDK)/sysroot/usr/include/`

Refs:
NDK - [Native Hardware Buffer](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/a-hardware-buffer) (android/hardware_buffer_jni.h)
Android/Java - [HardwareBuffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/HardwareBuffer.html?hl=JA#inherited-constants)
GrphicBuffer related article [Using OpenGL ES to Accelerate Apps with Legacy 2D GUIs](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-opengl-es-to-accelerate-apps-with-legacy-2d-guis)

NB: for Android 7 / API 24
Native API guide also says in [Graphics/EGL section](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/stable_apis.html#egl)

> API level 24 added support for the EGL_KHR_mutable_render_buffer,
>   ANDROID_create_native_client_buffer, and
>   ANDROID_front_buffer_auto_refresh extensions.

and [EGL_ANDROID_create_native_client_buffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/extensions/ANDROID/EGL_ANDROID_create_native_client_buffer.txt) is an EGL extension which contains `eglCreateNativeClientBufferANDROID()`, which returns `EGLClientBuffer`. (EGL/eglext.h)

Comment: And eglCreateNativeClientBufferANDROID must be use >= api24 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use SurfaceTexture, SurfaceTexture can create by MediaCore, SurfaceTexture can direct encode by MediaCore。This Plan can process 1080p video in 2ms-5ms per video frame。